# How do I make a forward and backward button in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, button

I'm trying to make a simple image viewer with Tkinter in Python. I'm having issues with the functions of the forward and backward buttons, the pictures are not changing even though the value for the images variable is changing.

```
# libraries
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
# main widget and tittle
root = Tk()
root.title("Image_viewer")

# counter for the image number

images = 0

# test function, this function is to test buttons


def test_func():
    global images
    print(images)
    print(image_list[images],)

# foward function


def foward_func():
    global images
    images = images + 1
    return images

# back function


def back_func():
    global images
    images = images - 1
    return images


# images import
image_1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(
    "C:\\Users\\hallo\\Pictures\\cool_pics\\coolpic1.jpg"))
image_2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(
    "C:\\Users\\hallo\\Pictures\\cool_pics\\coolpic2.jpg"))
image_3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(
    "C:\\Users\\hallo\\Pictures\\cool_pics\\coolpic3.jpg"))
image_4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(
    "C:\\Users\\hallo\\Pictures\\cool_pics\\coolpic4.jpg"))
image_5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(
    "C:\\Users\\hallo\\Pictures\\cool_pics\\coolpic5.jpg"))
# images list
image_list = [image_1, image_2, image_3, image_4, image_5]
# widgets
image_label1 = Label(root, image=image_list[images],)
exit_button = Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.quit)
back_button = Button(root, text="<", command=back_func)
forward_button = Button(root, text=">", command=foward_func)
test_button = Button(root, text="test", command=test_func)

# widgets print
image_label1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
back_button.grid(row=1, column=0)
exit_button.grid(row=1, column=1)
forward_button.grid(row=1, column=2)
test_button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3)

# main widegt loop
root.mainloop()
```

In theory, the image should change. I made the test button so I could verify in the terminal the value of images was changing, but still is not displaying a different picture.

Answer (score 0):

Just updating `images` does not update the image of `image_label1`.  You need to call `image_label1.config(image=image_list[images])` after updating `images`:

```py
# forward function
def foward_func():
    global images
    if images < len(image_list)-1:
        images += 1
        image_label1.config(image=image_list[images])
    # return value is ignored for button callback
    #return images

# back function
def back_func():
    global images
    if images > 0:
        images -= 1
        image_label1.config(image=image_list[images])
    # return value is ignored for button callback
    #return images
```

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that, issue solved, thanks a lot